# Building PoDoFo library using CMake and MinGW

Tags: c++, build, cmake, mingw, podofo

I am trying to build `PoDoFo Library` on my Windows Platform **(for use as an API)**. It is done using `CMake`. The `ReadMe` file says the following. Unfortunately I am new to CMake and I can't make out much from it.

> **Building PoDoFo on Windows**
>
> CMake 2.6.x is required for Windows. You can download it from
>   cmake.org .
>
> On Windows, PoDoFo may be built as either a shared or static library.
>   Building both is not supported. By default only the shared library
>   will be built. If you want a static library, just disable generation
>   of the shared library with the extra argument to cmake:

```
    -DPODOFO_BUILD_SHARED=FALSE
```

> **Handling library naming on win32**
>
> Especially on Windows it is also common for custom built libraries to
>   have different names to those you might download as pre-built copies.
>   CMake won't be able to find them if they're called something else
>   unless you tell it. Use these variables to tell CMake what names to
>   look for a library under:

```
•FREETYPE_LIBRARY_NAMES_DEBUG, FREETYPE_LIBRARY_NAMES_RELEASE and FREETYPE_LIBRARY_NAMES
•TIFF_LIBRARY_NAMES_DEBUG, TIFF_LIBRARY_NAMES_RELEASE and TIFF_LIBRARY_NAMES 
•LIBJPEG_LIBRARY_NAMES_DEBUG, LIBJPEG_LIBRARY_NAMES_RELEASE and LIBJPEG_LIBRARY_NAMES
•ZLIB_LIBRARY_NAMES_DEBUG, ZLIB_LIBRARY_NAMES_RELEASE,ZLIB_LIBRARY_NAMES
```

> **CMake builds on Windows with MinGW**
>
> Once MinGW is set up, make sure that the MinGW "bin" directory is on
>   your PATH, and be sure to set CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH and
>   CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH such that CMake can find the headers and .lib files
>   for the libraries PoDoFo requires. The GnuWin32 library packages from
>   http://gnuwin32.sf.net/ are known to work with PoDoFo, so installing
>   zlib, freetype, and libjpeg from there should do the trick.
>
> To configure and build PoDoFo with a default GnuWin32 install and with
>   MinGW already on your PATH:

```
md ..\podofo-debug 
cd ..\podofo-debug
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..\podofo-src -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=c:\progra~1\gnuwin32\include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=c:\progra~1\gnuwin32\lib -DPODOFO_BUILD_SHARED:BOOL=FALSE mingw32-make
```

I have installed `CMake` and downloaded the other libraries mentioned like `freetype, zlib, libjpeg`. Their header and binary files are in their respective folders.

Now what should `DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` and `DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` be? Also what is `"MinGW Makefiles"`? Do I have to supply any extra parameters?

I'll be grateful if someone can explain in simple steps how I can go about it.

**EDIT: error while executing CMAKE:**

```
-- Ensure you cppunit installed version is at least 1.12.0
Cppunit not found. No unit tests will be built.
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPack
ageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (message):
  Could NOT find FREETYPE (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStan
dardArgs.cmake:291 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindFREETYPE.cmake:75 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:372 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you followed all the instructions, to compile it should normally be enough to do:

```
cd <podofo root directory (where CMakeLists.txt is)>
mkdir build 
cd build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=<path to headers> -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to libraries> -DPODOFO_BUILD_SHARED:BOOL=FALSE ..
mingw32-make
```

Step by step:
First, go to the directory where your podofo sources are. You should see a `CMakeLists.txt` file lying around.

Second (and third), create (and go into) a directory where the compilation will be done. I call it build but it can be any name. This is a best practice since you can simply delete the build directory and come back to a clean state.

Fourth, ask cmake to create the makefile(s) for mingw:

- Specify the `PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED` like advertised in the manual: build shared or static version.
- `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CMAKE_LIBRAY_PATH` are used to reference to the packages needed to build podofo. If you downloaded the precompiled packages like you did since you have de headers and the binaries, then you need to give to cmake the path to those headers and binaries. You can specify the variables multiple times if needed, e.g.:

  ```
  cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/freetype/include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/freetype/lib  -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/zlib/include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/zlib/lib -DPODOFO_BUILD_SHARED:BOOL=FALSE ..
  ```
- The `"MinGW Makefiles"` tells cmake to create makefiles specific to mingw. Else, by default on windows, it creates makefiles specific to Microsoft Visual Studio.
- Finaly reference the `CMakeLists.txt` in the parent directory with `..` at the end.

Last, but not least, compile with the mingw version of make.

Comment: Right now there is no directory such as c:\progra~1\gnuwin32\include or lib. Do I need to install the dependent libraries like freetype etc or do I need to place their source files in the same directory c:\progra~1\gnuwin32\include and lib.

Comment: You need to specify where to find all the dependencies that podofo needs. You said you have the headers and the binaries of freetype, zlib and libjpeg. You simply need to give the locations where they are to cmake. `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` is for the headers and `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` is for the binaries (libraries). Is needed, you can specify those variables multiple times on the 4th command line in my example.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! I have actually got some success. However I am facing problem with the freetype library. Somehow cmake is not able to locate the include files. It says there is some fail report in the FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake. Any idea what could be the reason? I have edited my question to include the exact error message.

Comment: Did you add the correct path to freetype ? Did you install the dependencies like @Sergey suggests ? If not, you should try.

Comment: Thanks both of you! It worked after Sergey's suggestion of installing the libraries.

Answer (score 7):

To build PoDoFo you need installed [GnuWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getgnuwin32/files/), CMake, MinGW32 and PoDoFo sources

1. download [GetGnuWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getgnuwin32/files/latest/download?source=files)
2. install to c:\getgnuwin32
3. open cmd.exe
4. cd c:\getgnuwin32
5. `download.bat`
6. `install.bat`

Then as suggested in @ibizaman answer

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="C:\gnuwin32\include" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="C:\gnuwin32\lib" -DPODOFO_BUILD_STATIC=TRUE ..
```

FreeType should be installed with GnuWin32 packages

Comment: Thanks both of you! It worked after installing the libraries.

Comment: Actually this generates shared build Makefiles for podofo. This is despite the fact that the flag for shared=false is stated. How do I generate the static version?

Comment: Use -DPODOFO_BUILD_STATIC=TRUE to get static lib. Also updated the answer.

Comment: Yes Thanks! This generates the static build makefiles. However when I type in mingw32-make, podofo is built but I cannot locate any lib file. Only libpodofo.a is generated.

Comment: It is mingw-gcc archive (static library) format. It is normal.