# Building PoDoFo results in make errors

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw-w64, podofo

I have been trying to create a static library version of PoDoFo for API usage on my windows 10 computer. I was following the stack-overflow post: [Building PoDoFo library using CMake and MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042467/building-podofo-library-using-cmake-and-mingw) as instructions.

I followed the instructions are created and the output from the cmake was as follows:

```
C:\podofo-0.9.7\build> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="C:\getgnuwin32\.bat\include" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="C:\getgnuwin32\.bat\lib" -DPODOFO_BUILD_STATIC=TRUE ..
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED):
 Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
 CMake.

 Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
 CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
WANT_LIB64 unset; assuming normal library directory names
Will install libraries to C:/Program Files (x86)/PoDoFo/lib
-- Performing Test PODOFO_HAVE_UNIQUE_PTR
-- Performing Test PODOFO_HAVE_UNIQUE_PTR - Success
-- Looking for strings.h
-- Looking for strings.h - found
-- Looking for arpa/inet.h
-- Looking for arpa/inet.h - not found
-- Looking for winsock2.h
-- Looking for winsock2.h - found
-- Looking for mem.h
-- Looking for mem.h - found
-- Looking for ctype.h
-- Looking for ctype.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for BaseTsd.h
-- Looking for BaseTsd.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of long int
-- Check size of long int - done
-- Check size of int64_t
-- Check size of int64_t - done
Using gcc specific compiler options
-- Found ZLIB: C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/lib/zlib.lib
Found zlib headers in C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/include, library at C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/lib/zlib.lib
-- Found PkgConfig: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/pkg-config.exe (found version "1.8.0")
-- Checking for module 'libcrypto'
--   Found libcrypto, version 1.1.1l
-- Performing Test PODOFO_HAVE_OPENSSL_1_1
-- Performing Test PODOFO_HAVE_OPENSSL_1_1 - Success
-- Performing Test PODOFO_HAVE_OPENSSL_NO_RC4
-- Performing Test PODOFO_HAVE_OPENSSL_NO_RC4 - Failed
Found OpenSSL's libCrypto headers in C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include, library at crypto
-- Could NOT find LIBIDN (missing: LIBIDN_LIBRARY LIBIDN_INCLUDE_DIR)
Libidn not found. AES-256 Encryption support will be disabled
-- Found LIBJPEG: C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/lib/libjpeg.dll.a
Found libjpeg headers in C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/include, library at C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/lib/libjpeg.dll.a
-- Found TIFF: C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/lib/libtiff.dll.a
Found libtiff headers in C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/include, library at C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/lib/libtiff.dll.a
-- Found ZLIB: C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/lib/zlib.lib (found version "1.2.3")
-- Found PNG: C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/lib/libpng.dll.a (found version "1.2.37")
Found LibPng headers in C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/include;C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/include, library at C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/lib/libpng.dll.a;C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/lib/zlib.lib
-- Could NOT find UNISTRING (missing: UNISTRING_INCLUDE_DIR UNISTRING_LIBRARY)
LibUnistring not found. Unistring support will be disabled
-- Ensure you cppunit installed version is at least 1.12.0
Cppunit not found. No unit tests will be built.
-- Found OpenSSL: C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/lib/libssl.a
Found freetype library at C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/lib/libfreetype.dll.a, headers C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/include/freetype2;C:/getgnuwin32/.bat/include
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/modules/FindLIBSTLPORT.cmake:12 (SET):
 implicitly converting 'BOOLEAN' to 'STRING' type.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:413 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Checking for module 'fontconfig'
--   Package 'fontconfig', required by 'virtual:world', not found
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
 The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (Fontconfig)
 does not match the name of the calling package (FONTCONFIG).  This can lead
 to problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
 (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 cmake/modules/FindFONTCONFIG.cmake:41 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
 CMakeLists.txt:440 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find Fontconfig (missing: FONTCONFIG_LIBRARIES FONTCONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
 The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (Lua50) does
 not match the name of the calling package (Lua51).  This can lead to
 problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
 (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 cmake/modules/FindLua51.cmake:71 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
 cmake/modules/FindLUA.cmake:19 (FIND_PACKAGE)
 CMakeLists.txt:445 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find Lua50 (missing: LUA_LIBRARIES LUA_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
 The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (Lua) does
 not match the name of the calling package (LUA).  This can lead to problems
 in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables (e.g.,
 `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 cmake/modules/FindLUA.cmake:22 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
 CMakeLists.txt:445 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find Lua (missing: LUA_LIBRARIES LUA_INCLUDE_DIR)
Lua not found - PoDoFoImpose and PoDoFoColor will be built without Lua support
Building multithreaded version of PoDoFo.
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE
CMake Deprecation Warning at src/podofo/CMakeLists.txt:1 (CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED):
 Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
 CMake.

 Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
 CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


Building static PoDoFo library
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build
```

This output seemed alright to me so I moved onto doing a "mingwin32-make" call and this was the output after fixing some errors as per other sourceforge threads.

```
C:\podofo-0.9.7\build>make
[ 53%] Built target podofo_static
[ 54%] Linking CXX executable ContentParser.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontCache.cpp.obj):PdfFontCache.c:(.text+0x8f6): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Done_FreeType'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontCache.cpp.obj):PdfFontCache.c:(.text+0x9b3): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Init_FreeType'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontCache.cpp.obj):PdfFontCache.c:(.text+0x1c80): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Get_Postscript_Name'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_New_Face'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Load_Sfnt_Table'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Load_Sfnt_Table'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0x35e): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_New_Face'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0x7e3): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Done_Face'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0x8d4): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Open_Face'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0xbc4): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Select_Charmap'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0xc23): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Set_Charmap'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0xce8): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Load_Char'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0xe74): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Set_Char_Size'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0x1016): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Get_Sfnt_Table'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0x10df): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Get_Postscript_Name'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0x1349): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Load_Char'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0x1635): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Load_Glyph'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0x16ee): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Get_Name_Index'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0x1c3e): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Load_Char'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text+0x1d94): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Get_Char_Index'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp.obj):PdfFontMetricsFreetype.cpp:(.text$_ZN6PoDoFo14Scoped_FT_FaceD1Ev[_ZN6PoDoFo14Scoped_FT_FaceD1Ev]+0x25): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Done_Face'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0xab1): undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0xbdc): undefined reference to `deflate'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0xd96): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0xe33): undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0xf3b): undefined reference to `inflate'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0xf85): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0x1199): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0x1d28): undefined reference to `__imp_jpeg_destroy'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0x2030): undefined reference to `__imp_jpeg_std_error'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0x207b): undefined reference to `__imp_jpeg_CreateDecompress'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0x21ae): undefined reference to `__imp_jpeg_read_header'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0x21cb): undefined reference to `__imp_jpeg_destroy_decompress'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0x2231): undefined reference to `__imp_jpeg_start_decompress'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0x2312): undefined reference to `__imp_jpeg_read_scanlines'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0x2585): undefined reference to `__imp_jpeg_destroy_decompress'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp.obj):PdfFiltersPrivate.cpp:(.text+0x2762): undefined reference to `__imp_jpeg_resync_to_restart'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontCID.cpp.obj):PdfFontCID.cpp:(.text+0x489e): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Get_First_Char'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/podofo-0.9.7/build/src/podofo/libpodofo.a(PdfFontCID.cpp.obj):PdfFontCID.cpp:(.text+0x48eb): undefined reference to `__imp_FT_Get_Next_Char'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test\ContentParser\CMakeFiles\ContentParser.dir\build.make:113: test/ContentParser/ContentParser.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:807: test/ContentParser/CMakeFiles/ContentParser.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:135: all] Error 2
```

Could anyone help me fix this error. I have been searching the interwebs for a while now and have not found any similar errors. Could it be a problem with my cmake call?

Cheers.

Comment: My guess would be that the freetype library you've downloaded isn't compatible with your target compiler. You might find it easier to use Conan to download your dependencies, it has a recipe for podofo and should do all the work for you. `GetGnuWin32` doesn't look like it's been updated since 2009 and I'm guessing is 32-bit and you're probably trying to build 64-bit

Comment: Thanks I will try and give that a go :)